# the results of these two print are absolutely different

Tags: python

```
    n = 10
    s = [True] * (n)
    a = []
    def dfs(m):
        if m == 0:
            print(s) #(1)
            if s not in a:
                print(s) #(2)
                a.append(s)
            return
        for x in range(0, n, 2):
            s[x] = not s[x]
        dfs(m - 1)
        for x in range(0, n, 2):
            s[x] = not s[x]
        for x in range(1, n, 2):
            s[x] = not s[x]
        dfs(m - 1)
        for x in range(1, n, 2):
            s[x] = not s[x]
        for x in range(0, n, 3):
            s[x] = not s[x]
        dfs(m - 1)
        for x in range(0, n, 3):
            s[x] = not s[x]
    dfs(10)
```

why the first print(s) has many kinds of different s, but the second print(s) only have the initial s. I can't understand.How can I avoid this
problem when I use recursion when I use python

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "why the first print(s) has many kinds of different s, but the second print(s) only have the initial s""?

Comment: Please also explain what you expect how that code snippet should behave.

Comment: why list a only have one element after the function

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: len(a) only have one element , the function 'dfs' is to find how many kinds of status of the list 's' after performing exactly m  operations towards the three operations

Comment: if I print(len(a)), after "dfs(10)", it prints '1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When s gets appended to a the first time m is equal to zero, it is NOT appending a copy of the list s to a. It is appending a reference to s, so each time s changes, the contents of a change along with it. Your print #2 is only ever done once and `if not s in a` is only True the very first time.

Try this in a Python console to see a simpler example of this:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = []
>>> b.append(a)
>>> a[2] = 7
>>> b
[[1, 2, 7, 4]]
```